# SSAS MDX Calculated Measure Over Time

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, cube

I have a calculated measure that needs to cross join Customer and Product dimension then cross join a total sales measure to get a percentage for a specific customer sale.

```
[Measures].[Sale Value]  / [Measures].[Total Sales]
```

each measure has a link to the time dimension, and are set to last non empty.

The problem is that as I look at more information over longer periods (days, months, years etc) it gets slower and slower and slower. I am assuming this is because the calculated measure does its processing on the fly and there is no caching.

Is this correct? I have about 2000 customers and 50 products.

Please please help! any information about how to speed this up would be great.

Comment: You may want tot have a look at http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to set a many to many relationship between Customer/Prodcut and the  [Measures].[Total Sales] measure group.